# Unable to Extract Data from the Dictionary<String, Any> in swift

Tags: swift, swift4

I have a Dictionary<String, Any>  Data in the following format. I need to extract the values from it.I am unable to extract the values, initially it looked to me as JSON but it's of type Dictionary<String, Any>. Can anyone help me out.

```
 **{
        message =     {
            "pn_apns" =         {
                aps =             {
                    alert =                 {
                        body = "Andy - Picture added!";
                        roomId = 1611711512726;
                        title = "New chat on flag - New flag ";
                    };
                    sound = default;
                };
            };
            senderId = "XXXX@XXXXX";
            text = "Euclid%20Ave./Flag%20%26%20Chat/New%20flag%20/Original/1AF3956D-AEC4-485C-B8C2-3F97AEE05C58.png";
            type = P;
            uuid = "XXXXXXX-70CB-4301-DDDD-FFFFFFFF";
        };
        timetoken = 16117629931914202;
        uuid = "XXXX@XXXXX";
    }**
```

Comment: 1) That is not json, please post the raw json string 2) When printing the error then use `print(error)` instead for a more informative error message

Comment: Thanks for correcting me with that it's a Dictionary<String, Any>

Comment: Maybe you should start with reading up on [dictionaries](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID113)

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a JSON.

Look at https://www.json.org/json-en.html site.

To check the string, use https://jsonlint.com

Comment: Thanks it's of the type Dictionary<String, Any> in swift. It looked liked JSON to me. Thanks for correcting me